# Animation not working when use POPDecayAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-pop

I make dropping down animation for changing views. When I use `POPSpringAnimation` all working correctly. But when I change `POPSpringAnimation` to `POPDecayAnimation` nothing happens and in debug output I see this message:

```
ignoring to value on decay animation <POPDecayAnimation:0x7f9f2b5c8700; from = null; to = null; deceleration = 0.998000>
```

Code:

```
func switchViewController(from: UIViewController?, toViewController to: UIViewController?, animated: Bool) {

    if animated {
        to!.view.frame = self.view.frame
        // Not working when call trulySwitchViewController
        self.addChildViewController(to!)
        self.view.insertSubview(to!.view, belowSubview: from!.view)
        to!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        // Calculate new x coord
        var frame = from!.view.frame
        frame.origin.y += frame.size.height

        // POPDecayAnimation not working here
        var animation = POPDecayAnimation()
        animation.property = POPAnimatableProperty.propertyWithName(kPOPViewFrame) as POPAnimatableProperty
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect:frame)
        animation.completionBlock = {
            (_, _) in
            self.trulySwitchViewController(from, toViewController: nil)
        }

        from!.view.pop_addAnimation(animation, forKey: "dropDown")
    } else {
        to?.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.trulySwitchViewController(from, toViewController: to)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a decay animation you need to set the `velocity` property, this then decays to zero based on the `deceleration` property. So, the `to` property is not needed, the end state is determined based on the start position, velocity and deceleration.

You also need to animate the layer position not the view frame. So something like this should work...

```
var animation = POPDecayAnimation()
animation.property = POPAnimatableProperty.propertyWithName(kPOPLayerPosition) as POPAnimatableProperty

from!.view.layer.pop_addAnimation(animation, forKey: "dropDown")
```

Comment: Thank! But I don't understand why I should animate layer position instead of view frame

Comment: It might work, I am not 100% sure.. maybe its smart enough to apply the velocity to the origin.